# Is it a good idea to use a Screensaver on a raspberry pi as digital signage?

Tags: c, ssh, raspbian

I asked this question in the Raspberry PI section, so please forgive me for posting this here again. Its just there doesn't seem to be as active as this section of the forum. So, onto my question...

I have an idea and I'm working on it right now. I just wanted to see what the community's thought was on using a screensaver as digital signage. Every tutorial I've read shows someone using chromium in kiosk mode, and while that's fine and works well for some uses, it doesn't work for what I need. I have successfully completed a chromium kiosk, and it was cool. But the signage that I need to create now, has to work without internet. I've thought about installing LAMP locally on the PI, and still using chromium. I still may have to if this idea doesn't pan out. All I need from the signage is a Title Message in the top center, and a message body underneath it, with roughly 300-400 character limit. My idea is to write a screensaver module, in C, that will work with a screensaver such as xscreensaver. The module would need to be able to load messages from a directory on the pi. Then for my clients to update their signage text, I would write a simple client that sent commands as well as the text via SSH to the pi. I want to know what other people think about this. Is it a good idea? Bad idea? Should I "waste" my time doing something like this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am already using a rPi as digital signage, just over a year.  I am using two different setups:

version 1 uses Raspian loading xdesktop and qiv image viewer to cycle images stored on the Pi itself, synchronized with a remote server.  The problem I found was power and SD stability, when the power fails, which it will do no matter what, just when...  The Sd card can become corrupt due to all the writing that Raspian does all the time.  Certainly does not really need to write to SD.

version 2 uses a RO-filesystem and a command line image tool.  Uses the same process to show images from local, and sync with server.  But power fail causes no ill effects.

I am not using screensaver to display images, that seemed redundant to me, and unnecessary to wait for the SS to start just to display the images.

Some of the images are created using imagemagik, which is nicely dynamic where needed.